# Красивое облако-подсказка на html-странице

Tags: javascript, html, css

требуется при возникновении `ситуации` сфокусировать внимание пользователя на элементе страницы

хотелось выводить облако с подсказкой как на картинке, но без наведения кусора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

посоветуйте решение

Comment: при возникновении `ситуации`  показывайте облако с подсказкой........¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите функцию, которая принимает два аргумента:

- точку, где выводить облако (здесь можно использовать либо чистые координаты, либо принимать id элемента к которому нужно "цеплять" облако, а потом уже дёргать координаты из свойств этого элемента)
- текст подсказки (если нужно, чтобы он был разным в разных случаях).

Отображение облака можно реализовать двумя способами:

1. Заготовить его заранее, сделав невидимым, а при возникновении
   ситуации перемещать на нужные координаты, делать видимым, и (при
   необходимости) менять внутренний текст.
2. Либо конструировать программно внутри самой функции.

И при возникновении "события" запускайте функцию с нужными параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Я в таких случаях использовал http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Используйте метод .tooltip('show'). Весь CSS фреймворка тащить не нужно, можно взять только стили tooltip. Структура элемента очень простая, потому можно и самому написать пару строк CSS для него.

Данные для toolip задаются прямо в элементе, на который нужно обратить внимание, потому не придется указывать координаты элемента.

Посмотрите еще и popver. Возможно, он подойдет больше, чем toolip.

Comment: не то , это при наведении , автору надо что бы выскакивало самопроизвольно и я так понимаю что  js не знаком он

Comment: Если внимательно прочитать мой ответ, станет понятно, что .tooltip('show') отображает подсказку без наведения.

Comment: ааа , сорри - прошляпил я это

Answer (score 1):

Я использую на своих проектах - http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/JavaScript-tooltip